# PrintWriter

Tags: java, потоки-данных

У класса PrintWriter есть метод flush. в документации написано Flushes the stream. Перевести могу. только не понимаю, что именно делает этот метод. Не могли бы описать его действия?

Comment: Освобождает буфер?

Comment: Получается так. пишем сетевую игру. отправляю строчку. если не ставить flush() то появляются задержки. если ставить, то все отлично. а что именно он делает не пойму.

Comment: Ну переводя ответ @IronVbif на язык "на пальцах" -- непосредственно запускает вывод того, что накоплено в буферах, не дожидаясь момента, когда они будут заполнены и вывод запустится автоматически. @rasmisha "Освобождает буфер" -- довольно неоднозначное выражение.

Comment: @alexlz ну это я имел в виду, просто с красноречием у меня проблема

Comment: Рекомендую статью 90х годов "Дятлы и туканы" (например здесь: http://dibr.nnov.ru/n=812). Там как раз есть шутка про "очистку базы". А "освобождение буферов" можно понять и как освобождение выделенной под них памяти. Лучше неоднозначностей стараться избегать.

Comment: p.s. судя по наличию этого вопроса мой танец с бубном удался?:)

http://hashcode.ru/questions/111325/происходит-зависание-программы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

дело в том что после создания потоков записи они находятся в ждущем режиме. все что вы "пишите" на самом деле не отправляется а просто буферизируется. вероятно, что реальная операция "записи" произойдет когда буфер заполнится полностью. сам же поток знать не знает будет ли продолжатся передача, он ждет до тех пор пока вы не закроете поток.

если есть необходимость отправки данных без закрытия потока используется метод flush - принудительной "записи"

p.s. судя по наличию данного вопроса [танец с бубном удался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111325/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B) :)

Answer (score 0):

Обычно методы с такими названиями инициируют принудительный сброс буфера в нижестоящие инстанции.

Если вы обернули PrintWriter вокруг файла, то flush вызовет принудительную запись на диск содержимого буфера (думаю должны сброситься и JVM и системный буферы). В контексте записи в сеть это может быть инициация принудительной отсылки данных.